# Akka: Ask vs Tell

Tags: akka

I finished to read the Effective Akka book from Jamie Allen. I am fairly new to Akka, I cannot really get why at some point he says:

> However, there are a couple of things about it that are not ideal.
>   First of all, it is using futures to ask other actors for responses,
>   which creates a new PromiseActorRef for every message sent behind the
>   scenes. This is a waste of resources. It would be better to have our
>   actor send messages out in a “fire and forget” fashion and collect results 
>   asynchronously into one actor.

Using Ask instead of Tell seems generally to be more expensive. How much more expensive is using a Pull instead of a Push? And also, why is a Tell generally preferable compared to an Ask?

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand. Why does he say "This is a waste of resources"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of Effective Akka.  My point about using Ask was that you are using a Future.  If you aggregate multiple Asks into a single response, you created multiple timeouts for each Future that is behind the Ask.  In small doses, this isn't a terribly big deal, but in the large, it adds up to being an additional drag on performance.

Note that this book was written in 2013, and while most of it is still relevant, Akka Streams and the backpressure approach of Reactive Streams have negated some of the discussion around choosing between push and pull.  In any situation where either the producer(s) or consumer(s) could be overwhelmed, Akka Streams are definitely a better approach.

Thanks for reading the book, I hope you found it helpful!

Comment: Hello Jamie, thanks or the answer - yes, the best practices part is still very interesting. Do you think there are still applications for the Extra pattern then?

Comment: I do, though I prefer the Cameo pattern.  Any time you create something anonymous on the JVM, you lose ability to reason about it.  Lambdas, anonymous implementations of Java Interfaces, etc are all similar in this way.  Having explicit types is always cleaner and more maintainable.  Also, I like to aggregate responses from multiple services when I have three or more that I'm calling out to.  This lets me build domain-specific behavior about various failure conditions that could occur (2 of 3 responses come back, retry the third a few times, fail if that doesn't work, etc).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using a `tell` is preferred because:

> No blocking waiting for a message. This gives the best concurrency and scalability characteristics.
>
> There are performance implications of using ask since **something needs
>   to keep track of when it times out, there needs to be something that
>   bridges a Promise into an ActorRef and it also needs to be reachable
>   through remoting**. So always prefer tell for performance, and only ask
>   if you must. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/java/untyped-actors.html#Send_messages

If there is a case where you use `ask` in a place where `tell` could have been used, then you've wasted resources.  If you don't care about a response then why would you waste overhead (or resources) making your system return one.